# Problem while installing tensorflow on window 10 via Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

(venv) C:\Users\XYZ>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

> ERROR: tensorflow-1.13.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I am doing this on anaconda prompt.. First I am getting this Error "RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment." While setting virtual environment and then I am getting the Error above.

This is the error I am getting while trying to install tensorflow on Windows via Anaconda. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Try running `conda update --force conda` first, to deal with the the setuptools issue. Seems to be a recent bug that users are running into.